# How to uploadArchives to different folders depending on the maven artifact version?

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus, android-productflavors

I'm having some issues trying to figure out how can I upload to different folders regarding of the maven artifact version and then have the generated flavour jars/wars/aars inside that folder.

For example, I got an artifact with `version 1.0.0` and `groupId com.example`.
the issues is that when uploading this to **Nexus** the folder structures ends up being `com/example/10-flavor1` `com/example/10-flavor2`.

Here is what I got in gradle:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url:"http:/nexus/content/repositories/releases/") {
                authentication(userName: "username", password:"password")
            }

            addFilter('flavor1Release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("flavor1Release")
            }
            addFilter('flavor2Release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("flavor2Release")
            }

            pom('flavor1').artifactId = "artifactExample"
            pom('flavor1').version = "1.0.0"
            pom('flavor1').groupId = "com.example"

            pom('flavor2').artifactId = "artifactExample"
            pom('flavor2').version = "1.0.0"
            pom('flavor2').groupId = "com.example"
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way of customizing the repository request so we can pass the exact folder we need to create for each artifact.
Or anything that could do the job really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is against the philosophy of the [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) [Coordinates](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#pom-relationships-sect-more-coordinates) `groupId:artifactId:version`:

> *The three elements given above point to a specific version of a project letting Maven know who we are dealing with, ...*
>
> *Coordinates define a unique location for a project.* [...] *To review, a Maven Coordinate is made up of three components: ...*

The `<packaging>` type is not part of the coordinates, e.g.:

```
com.example:artifact1:1.0.0:jar
com.example:artifact2:1.0.0:war
```

becoming the repository folders and files:

```
+- com/example/artifact1/1.0.0
   +- artifact1-1.0.0.pom
   +- artifact1-1.0.0.jar
+- com/example/artifact2/1.0.0
   +- artifact2-1.0.0.pom
   +- artifact2-1.0.0.war
```

while you want:

```
com.example:artifactExample:1.0.0:jar
com.example:artifactExample:1.0.0:war
```

becoming:

```
+- com/example/artifactExample/1.0.0
   +- jar
      +- artifactExample-1.0.0.pom
      +- artifactExample-1.0.0.jar
   +- war
      +- artifactExample-1.0.0.pom
      +- artifactExample-1.0.0.war
```

Apart from the `<packaging>` type not being part of the coordinates (and, hence, the resulting folder structure) we see another problem there: We would have two POMs with identical coordinates while coordinates are intended to be identifying, i.e. unique.

Comment: Thanks for answering Gerold. What I wanted to know is if it would be possible to use the product flavor as part of the artifact so I can have a particular location depending on it, don't really mind about the packaging. Something like `com/example/artifactExample/flavor/1.0.0`.

Comment: Should be possible with **two** different projects/POMs (different coordinates requires different projects): 1) `<groupId>com.example.artifactExample.jar / <artifactId>artifactExample-jar` and 2) `<groupId>com.example.artifactExample.war / <artifactId>artifactExample-war`. One can argue whether to use the suffixes `...-jar` and `...-war` in the `<artifactId>`s or not. I'd prefer them for easy distinguishing of the flavor jars.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do that without modifying the groupId. Seems it's not going to be possible.